# Difference in Autobench between num_conn and low_rate / high_rate?

Tags: performance, scaling, load-testing, httperf, autobench

I'm running a load test using Autobench and httperf, and am having trouble understanding the example they give on their site. The example uses the flags

```
--low_rate 20 --high_rate 40 --rate_step 5 --num_call 10 --num_conn 5000
```

I get that this will start with 20 connections, and step up to 40 at a rate of 5 with 10 requests per connection. What I don't understand is what num_conn specifies. Are these like a "pool" of 5000 connections which the 20, 25, 30, etc. get pulled from? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the **rate**, autobench will make **num_conn** connections per test.  As **rate** increases, the duration per test decreases.

**num_conn** specifies the number of connections that will be made. (5000)

**num_call** specifies the number of calls (requests) per connection. (10)

**rate** specifies the number of connections per second. (20 initially)

So the total number of requests in a test is: **num_conn** * **num_call** (50000)

The duration of a test is: **num_conn** / **rate** (250 seconds initially)

The (attempted) requests per second in a test is: **num_call** * **rate** (200 initially)